# WPF - Content Presenter

Tags: wpf

I have created a resource dictionary for Button style and assigned it to a Button. The style appears in the button but I am not able to get the button text displayed. I have tried adding a content presenter but it didn't work. Please help.

```
 <Button  x:Name ="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="346,186,0,0"    
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{DynamicResource 
  ResourceKey=ButtonStyle}" Height="50">
       <ContentPresenter Name="MyContent">
            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                <Label>Click Me</Label>
            </ContentPresenter.Content>
        </ContentPresenter>

    </Button>
```

The style for button is as follows..It is created using Blend..

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Margin="0,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="#FF000000" RadiusX="23.489" RadiusY="23.489">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDE9090" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I also tried Button.Content> Click Button.Content> but not working.. Please suggest

Comment: You do not need `ContentPresenter` here. You can directly place Content within the `Button` tags. Also, post XAML for your style as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your button's `ControlTemplate` in Style missing a `ContentPresenter` to render the Content.

Add a `ContentPresenter` to the button's ControlTemplate. The resulting XAML for ControlTemplate would look like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Margin="0,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="#FF000000" RadiusX="23.489" RadiusY="23.489">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDE9090" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Also, like I said in my comment, you do not need a ContentPresenter in the XAML for Button itself. You could simply have your content between  and  tags.

```
  <Button
     x:Name="Submit"
     Width="75"
     Height="50"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     Margin="346,186,0,0"
     VerticalAlignment="Top"
     Style="{DynamicResource    ResourceKey=ButtonStyle}">
        Click Me
  </Button>
```

Read this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.100).aspx) page for more information on ControlTemplate.